# Encrypting emails sent with SMTP via TLS mutual authentification using S/MIME in Outlook

Tags: email, ssl, encryption, outlook

I'm creating a webapp where you can send an email through a contact form. This contact form will include sensitive information, so it needs to be encrypted.

I'm using a SMTP-server via Outlook to send my email, and it's being sent from a specific email-account and being received on a specific email-account (so the user doesn't fill out the sending or receiving email-account).

How do I encrypt the email content/body when the user submits the email? I'm already using TLS, but I want to encrypt the message/text within the mail itself.

Has anyone done anything similar previously? Any help would be appreciated! :)

I've tried setting up a certificate on the receiving client and uploading the certificate in the outlook app, but I don't think this is how it's supposed to be done.

I have a certificate and everything needed, but I don't know how to add the certificate to my code, I'm using [halojoy PHP-SMTP-Mailer](https://github.com/halojoy/PHP-SMTP-Mailer) (basically the same as PHPMailer).

Comment: 'Encrypt email *after* it's been sent' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, edited the question, hopefully it's easier to understand now :)

Comment: The encryption has to be done in your web application before the mail is transmitted to the mail server. It does not matter for this if TLS is used for transfer of the (encrypted) mail or not or if mutual TLS is used. Since nothing is known about your web application and framework/environment so it is impossible to point out something specifically. But something like [Sending Encrypted Email S/MIME with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830049/sending-encrypted-email-s-mime-with-php) might help you - i.e. search for S/MIME and the specific framework/environment you are using.